# HTML: Div Click function not working (amateaur)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a problem in the script:

```
$('.box').click(function () {$("input[type='image']").click(); });
```

I wish to click the `<p>` elements to upload an image file from the user pc.
When I use "brackets" to write my code, it also shows the errors:

1. `$` was used before it was defined.
2. missing `use strict` statement.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shivamkaushik14/jw4522p5/) is my code.

Am I coding wrong in javascript?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you jQuery script has been added?

Comment: I have added this:
`<script src='java.js'></script>`

Comment: Could you share that file?

Comment: It must be visible in the jsfiddle link.
anyways, here is the html code :
`<body>
  <script src='java.js'></script>
  <h1>Sample page</h1>
  <div class="pic">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="image" id="upload" />
      <p>...........</p>
      <p>Add Screenshot</p>
      <p>within this</p>
      <p>red border</p>
      <p>...........</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
`

Comment: I meant share java.js, what is the content in it? I added an external resource from jquery cdn and received no errors.

Comment: First step, you need to learn [How to use jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) unless you rename the jQuery library as `java.js`.

Comment: Replace your java.js with this script: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: I have added only the click function in java.js file. Just the line that I have posted in the question. Am I not using javascript correctly ?

Comment: Also note java is not javascript they are two VERY different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly following will help you

The `<input type="image">`is a graphical submit button.not the file upload button

For uploading file you need to use `<input type="file">`.

```js
$('div.box').on('click',function() {
  $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.pic {
  height: 638px;
  width: 938px;
  background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/sYpfIOEWajHnFESqdf0D4u1Kym0ErKpQ4gDn_Rwkxh3VxOrXw1cKgj-DZaNvVrAHpkhklQHNmBVHLhLbr57Le1699Hiibqm96oC-czexuHcn-LBkx5lKz_y9CQwvh_haCjDis7MDjhCOnIr2NU3eApw4ldE6riAo_PaqCH-oqDB2ZAIsFjiJTOqIEdAFBxSEWXNtVn4UOzqyk3y1ViAAS7XJ6gmxnh4zmVvIcUdzlhEOBKPIWnerm7OMBQ5N6zQK7pvgmHZ-SHEQWTpRN-B9ohdHsy8eHknlw7fYcUtI6JqOAZ0G93TJEuay-CU9WB8_3zf6OJsPpO-bWNa3AxEqeHRfUAHLiarTW_vBviDo6y8cvEIvGxe6OXGojbjSstRWq-Re-oYiZMkDnPuvloXETA7A84U9hGSkKU_eQoIpPhqOUH3diz1u8vVocWts6u7lOiHde7nqgrOEFQt1Cgu3jJaJ7oAzVEHeNWg7EhLQL33RQJEhL8p1R8X70QMttUkLEZjSVFNdSRKxEC7YZIj9gJel04Qz2Q8jwd3qcHZNaANwKI8TdAS0hWzDoPgWp1nATDM-Vx775-4Mpo7hR2Dr3hBR1ougQRm5p0-Rlqdft1gtqaM1JWfMr-TCfJE09ceJfUzGqR3Wfmr519NDpK_x317gh0_Z8kB8MwvYBKZS-g=w958-h638-no');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  transform: matrix3d(3.356071, -0.24874, 0, 0.002092, 0.702007, 2.436204, 0, -0.000061, 0, 0, 1, 0, 61, 147, 0, 1);
  transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.box>p {
  font-family: georgia;
  line-height: o.45em;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

#upload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Sample page</h1>
  <div class="pic">
    <input type="file" id="upload" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>...........</p>
      <p>Add Screenshot</p>
      <p>within this</p>
      <p>red border</p>
      <p>...........</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='java.js'></script>
</body>
```

**@ update based on comment:-**

When you change `$("p")` to `$(".box")` it will create recursive calls.
inorder to avoid this you need to place `<input type="file" id="upload" />` outside the div with class `box`.

Moreover you can place scripts and link tag anywhere in the document if you place it before body browser will load script before loading the body element and if you place it after body tag

Recomented way is loading the script after the body since it will load all the elements to DOM before the scripts is loaded it will improve the web page performance and also it will reduce the conflicts that cause the referring the DOM elements before loading

Comment: Thank you :D 
When I try to make the div "box" clickable instead of just the <p> elements, the code does not work by simply replacing $("p") with $('.box'). What can I do for that ?

Being new to javascript, I also do not understand the reason for the <script> element added before <body>.

Thank you in advance :D